# In YOLO, can there be more than one class within a cell?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, conv-neural-network, computer-vision, yolo

I'm confused by the fact that YOLO** can have multiple bounding boxes per cell, but there is only one class vector. Does YOLO allow the truth/training to have more than one object in a cell, each with a different class?  If so, how are the classes of each box encoded into the output and how does the loss function manage it?

** "You Only Look Once":  https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.02640.pdf